# cannot align flexbox properly with justify-content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to create a container which has two divs on top and each side, and another content at the bottom.
I have done this with flexbox. I can align the bottom content as I want, but the top content, aligns top, but not left and right. I thought that using

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

would dot it. I have also tried putting .social div with `margin-left: auto;`

This is my code:

```css
.boxes {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.branding {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="branding">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="social">social</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Case Study Title</h2>
    <p>A catchy description for our case study. We worked hard.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What have I missed out here?

-thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to make the boxes flex direction into column:

```css
.boxes {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;     /* add this */
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.branding {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;                  /* this seems to cause a big vertical gap that isn't in your original */
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="branding">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="social">social</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Case Study Title</h2>
    <p>A catchy description for our case study. We worked hard.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to make these two element `display: flex;` and remove the display flex on the container

```css
.boxes {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.branding {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="branding">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="social">social</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <h2>Case Study Title</h2>
      <p>A catchy description for our case study. We worked hard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```